# Is there a way to upload an image without having to input the absolute path for the image

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am coding with Selenium and Python 3. My current code to upload the image is this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="Filedata"]').send_keys("C:/Users/MyName/PycharmProjects/NikeSNKRS/profilepic.jpg")
```

I want to upload the image without having to input the whole path, but if I try the following code;

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="Filedata"]').send_keys("profilepic.jpg")
```

I get this error message:

*selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: path is not absolute: profilepic.jpg
(Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.183)*

Comment: You have to tell the browser where the file is; there's no getting around that.

Comment: `os.path.abspath("profilepic.jpg")`?

Comment: Thanks that works!

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that it was in the directory of the script.